# Execute Python Script with Command Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am pretty new in Python. I have created my first program script in pyhton, using spyder. I am getting below error when executing the python script through Command Prompt.

[image: When Ran through CMD]

Error - C:\Users\rkuma388\Documents\Project\Python>ETL_ProvJenny_ReportScreen_CoachListLoad.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rkuma388\Documents\Project\Python\ETL_ProvJenny_ReportScreen_CoachListLoad.py", line 10, in 
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

but when running in spyder, it is running fine and giving output.
[image: When Ran in Spyder]

Do I need to install any additional thing to make it execute in CMD ? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the options you can try:

1. Even though it is not a real solution, you can uninstall and reinstall numpy with pip.
2. Check whether you PATH is configured correctly to point to Python folder

Comment: Actually , numpy was not written in script. I don't need to import the numpy in my script. However, it was showing in error. Hence, I wrote in script. 
So do you want me to try the 1st step ?

Comment: Thank You. Ashok. I have upgraded the Anaconda and NumPy. It is working now.